# how to deploy a node.js app on Hekoku Error Routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

Hello I'm a beginner MERN developer, and I tried to deploy a node.js app in Heroku, so I created 2 routes '/' , '/posts' when I run (get '/') the server respond with "Home", that is OK. but when a run (get '/posts') the server shows me an error.

***GitHub Source:*** https://github.com/TribilinYT/react-crud-devcluna

[image: Aplication error]

```
package.json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
},
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
 "cors": "^2.8.5",
 "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "mongoose": "^5.12.5",
 "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
   }
}
```

Index.js

```
    //importing PKG's
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'

dotenv.config()

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

//import Routes
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/posts', postRoutes)
app.use(cors())

//Routes
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Home")
})

//connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.CONNECTION_URL, 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, ()=>console.log("Connected to DB!")
)


app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log("Listen on Port: ${port}")
})
```

Heroku Logs

```
enter code here
2021-04-23T21:09:47.559382+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:09:47.559382+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:09:47.943976+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:09:47.943976+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:10:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:11:04.283329+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:11:04.283329+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c06105e1 by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:11:04.296824+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user jobs.cluna@gmail.com
2021-04-23T21:11:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-23T21:11:07.847834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-23T21:11:10.433903+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-23T21:11:10.433921+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-23T21:11:10.433921+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-04-23T21:11:10.433921+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-23T21:11:11.359978+00:00 app[web.1]: Dalas
2021-04-23T21:11:11.627392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-23T21:11:41.458803+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to DB!
2021-04-23T21:11:59.048613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=acb3efea-c86b-4b59-b8eb-105202c5d7c0 fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=304 bytes=181 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:12:41.469874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/posts" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=a58a8262-5f22-4702-bfc0-408ee40ae2b9 fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:13:48.161257+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=3b5b51b7-5b9e-46ff-a84b-c18ae94e0fbb fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=234 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:13:48.829585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=703ae56f-432c-489d-a974-b25ac0977fc7 fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:14:12.032893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/posts" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=0b4d2f55-2b28-4304-842f-a908b7e1fb9e fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:18:43.738769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/post" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=c3b96d2f-1f02-47a4-b447-fdf65e840742 fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=419 protocol=https
2021-04-23T21:19:17.600884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/posts" host=react-crud-devcluna.herokuapp.com request_id=24b23a5d-7161-42bc-89f2-af93c6fd0268 fwd="190.XXX.XXX.XXX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Post Request
[image: Post Request]

Get Request
[image: Get Request]

console.log /posts get Request
[image: Get request /posts]

I dont understand what error did it. I follow a lot of tutorials, and any information helps me.

Comment: can you post the content of ./routes/posts.js file?

Comment: either, just appear another error message, i going to upload the files to github

Comment: I checked your github code, you are likely ending up in the catch() and there you don't return anything.

do a console.log inside the catch to see what error it is giving

Comment: I updated the post, with the response in console, I have to mention that the app works fine in localhost.

Comment: You should open the heroku logs, and then do a request, the console.log will appear inside Heroku logs, not in Postman